# find and replace texts using jquery

Tags: jquery, text, replace

I am trying to find and replace texts using jquery.

```
function replaceText() {
    var jthis = $(this);
    $("*").each(function() { 
        if(jthis.children().length==0) { 
            jthis.text(jthis.text().replace('nts:', 'nights:')); 
        } 
    });
}
$(document).ready(replaceText);
$("html").ajaxStop(replaceText);
```

here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2GENx

I need to replace the all "nts" texts on the page by "nights". Can you tell me why it's not working?

Comment: Your problem is `$("html").ajaxStop(replaceText);` never triggered. Just put break point into beginning of replaceText function. And count how many times it called. It should be called two times. First when document is ready. Second when Ajax load completes. Another problem as others explained you should also modify replaceText function logic as one explained bellow.

Comment: okey please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/2GENx/9/ this doesn't work either. nor this http://jsfiddle.net/2GENx/10/

Comment: It is wrong again your ajax call does not completed and you are trying to replace your data. How it is possible?

Comment: You should be sure that you are calling your replaceText after ajax call completed.

Comment: where are you calling your ajax call?

Comment: I am bit lost. Tryin to work this out since 2 hours. Can you please update the jsfiddle?

Comment: No I cannot because I cannot find out where you are calling ajax request. It should be in your external files. However your external files all minimized. It is hard to analyze your minimized code.

Comment: yes it is in external file. I am just trying to include this external page to my page by changing the texts.

Comment: I am including it using `echo file_get_contents($url);` just wanted to show you the source code on jsfiddle. So in this case it is impossible to change the text because its unknown when request is finishes?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have tried to avoid writing `$(this)` all the time by storing its value in `jthis`; the problem is that by doing so you effectively always inspect the same item.

Instead, save the reference inside the `each()` callback:

```
function replaceText() 
{
    jQuery("*").each(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if ($this.children().length==0) { 
            $this.text($this.text().replace('nts:', 'nights:')); 
        } 
    });
}
```

It also seems that you're using jQuery next to something called [wisdomweb](http://www.wisdomweb.ru/) on your page, and that doesn't support the `.ajaxStop()` feature; the only suggestions I can give you:

1. hack the library to support `.ajaxStop()`,
2. listen for [dom changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom) and perform the replacement inside,
3. use an even uglier setTimeout() option.

Comment: @antindexer what you mean by "jsFiddly under console" I don't have any error on my chrome console. please can you explain If you have noticed where the problem is. 
Jack This didn't work either. please see: http://jsfiddle.net/2GENx/5/

Comment: Sorry for putting -1 to your answers. Please update your answer and I will be able to remove it.

Comment: @hijacker83 The problem is that you're using jQuery but `$w` is not jQuery at all, it's from wisdomweb. Currently it seems that they have no way to know when an AJAX request has finished.

Comment: @Jack please update your answer then I can remove -1.

Comment: @Jack  I am including it using `echo file_get_contents($url);` just wanted to show you the source code on jsfiddle. So in this case it is impossible to change the text because its unknown when request is finishes?

Comment: @hijacker83 If you're doing that with PHP, why not do the replacement there as well then?

Comment: @Jack because of "nts" doesn't exist on page load (please click to "show source code" on your browser you will see that actualy "nts" texts doesn't exists it is requested later) and I thought the only way is to change it by using jquery after page is loaded.